# "Stray start tag footer" in html validator?

Tags: html, css, validation

I cannot work out why I am getting this error:

Stray start tag footer.

This is the code (I took the content out, this is just the tags)

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="heading.jpg" width="840" alt="pic">
    <!--<div id="container"></div> used ot set width of page -->
    <nav>
        <div id="columns">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <a href="gift_ideas.html">Gift Ideas</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="link">
            <a href="link1.html">link1</a>|<a href="link2.html">link2</a>|<a href="link3.html">link 3</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <br>
        <div id="homePage">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <br>
            <div id="cart">
                <img src>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<footer>
    <br>
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    Email: <a href="email@example.co.nz">email@example.co.nz</a>
    <img src>
</footer>
```

I am sure i have closed every tag, so what is the problem with the footer?

Comment: I don't see a `<html></html>`, but your footer looks okay.

Comment: It also probably doesn't help that the footer is outside the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to move the `</body>` end tag at the very end, because a `footer` element must not appear after the `body` element but inside it. This follows from the syntax of the root element, the [`html` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html): it contains a `head` element and a `body` element, nothing more.

The validator says “Stray start tag footer” because the start tag appears in a context where no elements can be started – after the `</body>` tag, where only the optional `</html>` tag may appear.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `<html>` tags added, `<footer>` brought inside `<body>` tag. While not directly related to your question, it would also appear you are using `<br>` tags to make space between various elements. I would suggest you stop doing that, and use CSS to adjust the `margin` properties of those elements instead.

Complete code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="heading.jpg" width="840" alt="pic">
    <!--<div id="container"></div> used ot set width of page -->
    <nav>
        <div id="columns">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="products.html">Products</a>
            <a href="gift_ideas.html">Gift Ideas</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="link">
            <a href="link1.html">link1</a>|<a href="link2.html">link2</a>|<a href="link3.html">link 3</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <br>
        <div id="homePage">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <br>
            <div id="cart">
                <img src>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <br>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        Email: <a href="email@example.co.nz">email@example.co.nz</a>
        <img src>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```